# Is there any way to debug redirection rules in.htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache, redirects, iis, isapi-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file with over 200 redirection rules. It seems some of them are conflicting each other.

Is there any way to find out which one is responsible of redirect on a particular request?

Please note, I'm using ISAPI_Rewrite from HeliconTech (similar syntax to Apache mod_rewrite) over IIS 6.

Comment: Don't use IIS6 but you should have some kind of logging and you should be able to find your problems in there if any exist.

Comment: Its a stable application....and I want change the environment; not even upgrade the IIS version :(

Comment: Not what I said, you must have some kind of logging.

Comment: Ah I see what your misunderstood my bad - I meant `I don't use IIS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RewriteLog](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteLog.htm) and [RewriteLogLevel](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteLogLevel.htm) directives to log such activity (IIS restart most likely will be required).

The higher value you put for `RewriteLogLevel` the more verbose/detailed it will be.

If your site is busy (has lots of requests) then you will have hard times debugging it (log will become huge in a matter of seconds/minutes and it will become quite hard to see what is going on there (where one request ends and another starts etc)) .. so try it on your dev machine or when not busy if possible.